# About the method "select" and "join"

Tags: ruby, methods, definition

so I posted a question earlier about displaying factors of non-prime numbers and got this as a solution.

Below is a part of the code, but I have a little bit trouble understanding a few terms in them (since I am relatively new to ruby).

```
def factors(n)
   (1..n/2).select{|e| (n%e).zero?}.push(n)
 end
```

For instance,

- What does the method select do in general?
- What does .zero? do?

Then,

```
puts "#{n} is not a prime number =>#{factors(n).join(',')}"
```

What does .join(',') do?

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can explain these terms to me in basic terms or simple concepts.

Comment: See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/

Comment: did you try looking those methods up in the documentation?

Comment: It would help if you could tell us, what *precisely* you don't understand about the documentation of those methods, so that the authors of the documentation can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` method filters a collection. You specify the condition (the predicate) in the block and `select` returns items who match that condition.

```
[1,2,3,4].select(&:even?)
 => [2, 4]
```

`i.zero?` is another way to write `i == 0`

```
[0,2,3,0].select(&:zero?)
 => [0, 0]
```

`join` method concatenate a collection as a string with the parameter as a separators between items

```
[0,2,3,0].select(&:zero?).join(' and ')
 => "0 and 0"
```

Note

```
[1,2,3].select(&:even?)
```

is a simpler way to write

```
[1,2,3].select { |item| item.even? }
```

Answer (score 1):

i will try explain by following links and text from documentation

[join()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

Returns a string created by converting each element of the array to a string, separated by the given separator. If the separator is nil, it uses current $,. If both the separator and $, are nil, it uses empty string.

```
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join        #=> "abc"
[ "a", "b", "c" ].join("-")   #=> "a-b-c"
```

[select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select)

Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value.

If no block is given, an Enumerator is returned instead.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].select { |num|  num.even?  }   #=> [2, 4]

a = %w{ a b c d e f }
a.select { |v| v =~ /[aeiou]/ }  #=> ["a", "e"]
```

[zero?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-zero-3F)

```
zero? → true or false
Returns true if num has a zero value.
```

Ruby html documentation: [ruby-doc.org](https://ruby-doc.org/)

Comment: Well, link-only answers are not useful. Either post as a comment, or elaborate, so that your answer still makes sense when/if links go dead.